# Counting the number of capital letters in an input?- in python

Tags: python-3.x

On python how do you make a program that asks for an input and the program works out the number of capital letters in that input and output the number of capital letters?

Comment: ----------->[`str.isupper()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper)<------------

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the string and use [`.isupper()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) to check if the letter is uppercase and increment the count. Finally print the count.

```
inpt = raw_input('Enter something: ')
c = 0

for i in inpt:
    if i.isupper():
        c += 1

print "No. of uppercase letters: ", c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
len(filter(lambda x:isupper(x),list(input("Enter String"))))
```

Comment: Since OP is new to Python, I don't think it's a good idea to suggest `filter` or `lambda` without an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function:

```
def capital(word):
    num = 0
    for char in word:
        if char.isupper():
            num+=1
    return num
```

And incorporate it as such:

```
word = input('Enter: ')

print capital(word)
```